How to send different ddtags for different files read by filelog receiver?
I am trying to set up the OpenTelemetry collector to send logs to Datadog using the Datadog exporter. Here is what the relevant portion of my configuration file looks like:
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
  filelog:
    include:
        - /data/portal-cron/logs/validation_utils_py3.json
        - /data/portal-cron/logs/cvr-fetcher.log
    start_at: beginning
    attributes:
      ddtags: host:pipelines3.cbioportal.aws.mskcc.org

This will cause all events sent to Datadog to be tagged with host:pipelines3.cbioportal.aws.mskcc.org. But let's say I only want to apply this tag to events read from cvr-fetcher.log. Is it possible to do this, either by defining multiple filelog receivers or applying some setting I'm missing? I have looked at the receiver schema here, but I could not find anything.
